# How to avoid execution of not imported exports using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a sort of circular dependency using Webpack and I want to know if I can fix it without changing imports.

I have FILE_A:

```
import {named_export} from 'FILE_B';

let x = do_stuff_with(named_export);
export default x;
```

and FILE_B

```
import x from 'FILE_A';

export named_export = 'Something'
export default something_that_depens_on(x);
```

My problem is that, when I import `{named_export}` in FILE_A, it triggers also the execution of `something_that_depens_on(x)` in FILE_B and my code crushed since x is `undefined`.

There is the possibility to import `named_export` without triggering the evaluation of the other lines of code in FILE_B or I have to create a new file only to export `named_export`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it differently, instead of FILE_A taking named_export from FILE_B you can call a function from FILE_B passing variable inside of FILE_B.

```
// FILE_A
export function do_stuff_with(named_export) {
  const x = "test";
  return x;
};

// FILE_B
import {do_stuff_with} from 'FILE_A';
const named_export = 'Something';
const x = do_stuff_with(named_export)
export something_that_depens_on(x);
```